# Generalized Gronwall inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let's suppose to have the following inequality
$$f(t)\leq g(t)+\int_s^t\int_s^{t'}f(r) dr dt'\,.$$
Is there a Gronwall's type inequality to bound $f(t)$?

Comment: Is $s$ just some fixed value?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes it is ($s<t$)

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but the double integral is equal to $\int_s^t (t-r)f(r)dr$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hint from Martin R plus the generalized Gronwall inequality from Lemma 2.7 in [G. Teschl, Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf).

Comment: How exactly would the Lemma 2.7 apply in this case? As the the comment of Martin R, the integrant contains a dependency in $t$ (the integral bound) in the term $(t-r)$. Such a dependency does not appear in your Lemma.

Comment: You are right, a comment about this is in order! However, note that you can replace the $t-r$ by the maximum over the interval under consideration, say $[0,T]$ (I am using $s=0$ for simplicity of notation). Then you get $f(t) \le g(t) + \int_0^t g(s)(T-s) \exp(\int_s^t (T-r) dr) ds$ for $t\le T$. Now finally note that you can choose $T=t$ which gives $f(t) \le g(t) + \int_0^t g(s)(t-s) \exp(\int_s^t (t-r) dr) ds$.